# How to differentiate between branch trigger and the scheduled trigger in azure DevOps build pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to run different jobs in build pipeline for branch trigger and scheduled trigger.

`branch trigger => run job 1`

`scheduled trigger => run job 2`

Is there any way to **differentiate between the triggers**? So that i will be running my jobs according to that differentiating condition.

**My thought process**

I was thinking of setting variable during scheduled trigger, hence i could use that variable in the job condition evaluation. But I was not able set the variable.

```
# Sample azure-build-pipeline.yml file


variables:

# by default the variable is false
  isScheduledTrigger: false


trigger:
  - develop
  - master

schedules:
  - cron: "0 0 * * *"
    displayName: Daily midnight build
    branches:
      include:
        - develop
    always: true
# somewhere here i want to set the isScheduledTrigger variable to TRUE

jobs:
 - job: Branch trigger job
   condition: or(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'develop'),eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master'))
   steps:
# Multiple steps for branch trigger



- job: Scheduled trigger job
   condition: and(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'develop'),eq(variables['isScheduledTask'], True))
   steps:
# Multiple steps for scheduled trigger
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can differentiate the type of Trigger using the variable named Reason

```
condition: and(succeeded(), and(not(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')), not(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule'))))
```

Comment: [Build.Reason documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)